# リストから日本語以外の要素を削除したい

Tags: python, 正規表現

様々なstr要素が含まれるリストから、日本語（ひらがな、カタカナ、漢字）以外の物を削除するコードを書いたのですが、何度も実行しないと全て消えてくれません。どうやら数字、アルファベットは一括で消すことが出来ても、記号を一つ消すたびにbreak(?)してしまうように見えるのですが・・・どうしたらいいのでしょうか。

```
import re
bag_of_things = ["あいうえお", "546", "たぬき", "饅頭", "abdf", "#%&", "aodih", "    ", "hello", "こんにちは"]
nihongo = re.compile('[ぁ-んァ-ン一-龥]+')


def clean(list):
    for item in list:
        if not nihongo.findall(item):
            print(item, "is not japanese")
            list.remove(item)
```

[[image: 結果[1]]

[image: 関数]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for文の途中で、forで回しているlistの要素を削除しているため、対象オブジェクトがずれてしまっているのが原因です。

```
>>> L = list(range(10))
>>> L
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> for l in L:
...     print(l)
...     L.remove(l)
... 
0
2
4
6
8
>>> L
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

対処方法はいくつかあります。
1. すでに自己解決されているように、対象リストから`remove`するのではなく対象を抽出して別のリストにいれるか。
2. ループは対象リストのコピーに対して行うか。

```
>>> L = list(range(10))
>>> for l in L[:]:
...     print(l)
...     L.remove(l)
... 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
>>> L
[]
```

Answer (score 3):

既に解決済みとの事ですが、 reversed() 使っても良いのでは?

```
def clean(list):
  for item in reversed(list):
        if not nihongo.findall(item):
              print(item, "is not japanese")
              list.remove(item)
```

単に逆順からの検索を行うだけです。

---

追記

もっと簡単な方法がある筈と思ったら、

> **filter**(lambda item: nihongo.findall(item), list)

で良いみたいですね。

Comment: reversed()で良いかと思ったのですが、単にクローンを作っているだけでした。 元は、index使って逆順に調べ、後ろから、削除する方法。 これは、 for i in range(len(list), -1, -1): で、list.pop(i) 。もう一つだったので、 reversed() としたのですが、全くダメですね。 ただ、この手のリストは、後ろから削除すれば、順番は変わりません。 参考までに。

Answer (score 2):

申し訳ないです、自己解決しました。。。
日本語の要素だけを含む新しいリストを作りました。。。

```
nihongo = re.compile('[ぁ-んァ-ン一-龥]+')  # used in def clean(list):


def clean(list):
    new_list = []
    for item in list:
        if nihongo.findall(item):
            new_list.append(item)
    return new_list

list = clean(list)  # 日本語ワードだけを含むリストを作成。
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
def clean(list):
  return [e for e in list if nihongo.findall(e)]

bag_of_things = clean(bag_of_things)
```